# Pushsafer en Spyder y en SublimeText3, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pushsafer'

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, spyder

estoy intentando utilizar Pushsafer en Python 3.7.7 de tal forma que me notifique de si mi script ha finalizado o ha ocurrido algun error. He descargado e instalado el paquete mediante

```
pip install python-pushsafer
```

y aparentemente esta instalado.

```
Requirement already satisfied: python-pushsafer in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=1.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-pushsafer) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=1.0->python-pushsafer) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=1.0->python-pushsafer) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=1.0->python-pushsafer) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests>=1.0->python-pushsafer) (2.8)
```

Cuando ejecuto el script con SublimeText3, funciona y recibo la notificación en mi móvil. No obstante, cuando lo hago con Spyder aparece el siguiente error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pushsafer'
```

Alguien sabe a que se puede deber?
Gracias.

Comment: Éstos errores son casi siempre por que usa un interprete distinto al que instalaste el paquete. Asegurate de que Spyder está ejecutando el script usando el intérprete en el que instalaste el paquete.

Comment: Hoja @FJSevilla. No entiendo muy bien tu comentario. Podrías indicarme como puedo verificarlo? Gracias

Comment: En una terminal del sistema haz `pip -V` y mira la ruta del interprete al que pertenece pip, es en ese intérprete en el que instalas, luego en Spyder mirate ésto: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43592879/7131499, debes usar el mismo intérprete en ambos casos, o instalas en el que usas en Spyder o cambias el que Spyder usa.

Comment: Gracias! Problema resuelto.